# How can malware force install Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, extension

As the title says, I can't seem to understand how a program installs an Chrome extension. You can't just copy paste the extension files into the client computer because Chrome deletes those file when you startup. When you install the extension using Windows registry, you still get the option to delete it. How can a extension like this one: `cdhidgolhfepblnlffkkifjnikbfkood` be installed and not deleted?

Answer (score 0):

As the title says, I can't seem to understand how a program installs an Chrome extension. You can't just copy paste the extension files into the client computer because Chrome deletes those file when you startup. When you install the extension using Windows registry, you still get the option to delete it. How can a extension like this one: cdhidgolhfepblnlffkkifjnikbfkood be installed and not deleted?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).